# Changing text cell background color in google colab

Tags: jupyter-notebook, google-colaboratory

I tried to change background for some parts of text cells of my jupyter notebooks to make it more stylish as they are shared as documents on google colab. However, I could not get it done by adding html style in text cells.

It does work if I run as html in **code** cells like below

```
%%html
<style>
div.someClass {    
    color: #000000;
    background-color: #80ced6;
    }
 </style>
<div class=someClass>
some text
...
</div>
```

I wonder is there anyway to make it work also for text cells?